# Changing Y position constraints programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, nslayoutconstraint

[image]
This is four button open new view between them.

I set constraints through Xcode, and want to change position programatically, but it does not work. I am new, kindly help. I used

```
[_btn_patientInformation.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints: NO];
NSLayoutConstraint *constraintCoordinatesCenterY =[NSLayoutConstraint                                                  constraintWithItem:_btn_patientInformation attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:coordinatesView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1.0 constant:1];
```

But unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: use outlet for the constraint you want to change

Comment: i set all outlet constraints from the xcode and now wants to change from coding.

Answer (score 3):

Use outlet for the constraint you want to change.

The outlet will be looking like this:

```
 @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint * topPositionConstraint;
```

Connect the above constraint to the Y constraint in storyboard.

And to change the constraint, you can simply do:

```
  topPositionConstraint.constant=yourValue;
```

and dont forget to call

```
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

after the change in constraints.

Try to set the constraints this way:

- Select the top button, and give leading,trailing,top,height,width constraint.

[image]

- Now select the second button, and ctrl drag it to first button, and release the mouse click, and select vertical spacing and leading constraint.

[image]
[image]

- Do the same for the third button,except you ctrl drag the third button to the second button.

[image]

Now to move all these buttons up or down , you can simply change the top constraint for the first button.

Comment: i want to change y position of btn but it does not works

Comment: do not try to change the button frame to change its position, if you really want to change the buttons top constraint

Comment: can you post the screenshot of your button on your storyboard with constraints ?

Comment: that is four button screen when i click sender infromation button it open little view with button and other three button moves down with same space

Comment: how did u set the constraints for all of those buttons

Comment: i mean, what type of constraints did you set for each of those buttons?

Comment: leading trailing top and bottom for each button

Comment: also height and width

Comment: I suggest you to set all constraints for the top button, and the bottom button constraints should be relative to its top

Comment: so that if you move button1, all other buttons will be moved